# Selenium IDE Drop Down Menu Item

Tags: drop-down-menu, selenium-ide

I am using **Selenium IDE** and I have a dynamic **drop down** menu that I need to select a specific value from. The test works fine until it gets to the part where it must select the item. 
My commands so far include:

```
    type     | id=finditem | se
    typeKeys | id=finditem | se
```

And at this point I have a **drop down** menu with nothing selected. I used FireFinder to find that the drop down item that I have to select has this:

```
<<"a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">>
```

I also used Firebug to inspect the element and found this CSS path:

```
html body ul.ui-autocomplete li.ui-menu-item a.ui-corner-all
```

If anyone has any suggestions that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: what is your question? do you want to select a item from dropdown using **Selenium IDE**??

Answer (score 2):

Use following Command

```
command select               
Target css=yourdropdowncss   //Css or xpath of that dropdown
Value label=firstitem        //option from dropdown you want to select
```

Try it..

Answer (score 0):

I used the below code to select an dynamic value in drop down box and it makes the miracle.

```
   <tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>name=cmb_text_xxx</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
        <td>mouseOver</td>
        <td>css=a:contains(&quot;xxx&quot;)</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>mouseDown</td>
        <td>css=a:contains(&quot;xxx&quot;)</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since none of the mentioned solutions worked (I had a text-field that would work only if the drop-down is generated by inputting a real address, then clicked) this was my solution:

```
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=address</td>
    <td>1 Eglinton Avenue East, Toronto, ON M4P 1P1, Canada</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>keyDown</td>
    <td>id=address</td>
    <td>\40</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>keyDown</td>
    <td>id=address</td>
    <td>\40</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=ui-active-menuitem</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Edit: You may also need to assert/wait for the dropped-down menu (id=ui-active-menuitem) is present first. However, it will fail if the speed is set to "fast", so try it at a medium.

Answer (score 0):

(select target by clicking on main drop down:)

```
mouseover target= xpath:idRelative value= blank
```

(select target by clicking on the specific drop down:)

```
mouseover target= xpath:idRelative value= blank
```

(then:)

```
clickAndWait target=[same as above specific xpath] value=blank
```